# How to find the largest difference in change in an array? - java

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I declare an array:

```
int[] arr = {10,2,7,11,3};
```

The largest (positive) change in this array would be 9 as 11 - 2 = 9.

How would I write a method that find the largest change in code with the smaller integer occurring earlier?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you just sort the array and do `a[a.length-1] - a[0]`?

Comment: You just posted this like 15mins ago and got downvoted to oblivion for not even attempting a solution. Why don't you *try* something and post what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I rewrote the answer since I misunderstood the question.**

The simplest but almost certainly not the most efficient way to do this is to check every change and comparing it to the previous one. If it is bigger, discard the previous one and remember this one instead.

```
int change = arr[1] - arr[0]; //give it an initial value, if we find a bigger change we will replace it
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; i < arr.length; j++) {
        if(arr[j]-arr[i] > change) {
            change = arr[j]-arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This will still give an answer even if there are no positive changes. If you do not want that, you can modify it. It is trivial.

Keep in mind that `arr.length - 1` is important in the outer loop.

Comment: But what if the array were to be declared as {13,15,2,6,12}? It wouldn't work in this case as the largest change would be 12-2 = 10. 15 - 2 would only work if the 2 were before it.

Comment: Oh. You did not make it clear that it should behave like this in your question. Edit incoming.

Comment: I think that the first for-loop needs to have i start at 0. You can look at my solution below

Comment: @michael You are right. I thought since we had the initial `arr[1] - arr[0]` that would not be needed, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to find the smallest number and the largest number in the list and comparing it with the largest number on the list.

1. List first item as minimum.
2. Compare to next item and if greater, assign that number as lesser.
3. List first item as largest.
4. Compare to next item and if smaller, assign that number as greater.

At the end of the list, you will have the least and the greatest number. The difference will be the difference between the smallest and the largest.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! You could brute-force this pretty easily, as I'm still thinking for a more creative solution.

```
int [] arr = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
int biggestDifference = arr[1]-arr[0];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if ((arr[j] - arr[i]) > biggestDifference) {
            biggestDifference = arr[j] - arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the array would ensure that the smallest number will always be at the front and largest at the back.

```
     public static void main(String []args){
        int[] arr = {10,2,7,11,3};     
        int diff = findBiggestDiff(arr);
        System.out.println(diff);
     }

     public static int findBiggestDiff(int[] arr){
         Arrays.sort(arr);
        int diff = arr[arr.length-1] - arr[0];
        return diff;
     }
```